# Python looping back in a range when stop is exceed a value?

Tags: python, range

I have a range in like below. What I am trying to do is to loop back to 0 if the range stop is greater that a certain value (this example 96). I can simply loop through the range as I did below, but is there a better way to do perform this in Python's range?

```
my_range = range(90, 100)

tmp_list=[]
for i in range(90, 100):
    if i >= 96:
        tmp_list.append(i-96)
    else:
        tmp_list.append(i)

print(tmp_list)
[90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Can you just use modulo, e.g. `tmp_list.append(i % 96)`?

Comment: `range` accepts up to 3 parameters. `range(start, stop, step)`. You need to write wrapper, that would invoke range with negative step if `start` > `stop`. [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, but what difference does it make? `(i-96)` and `(i % 96)`... so?

Comment: There is a difference if there are values greater than 192 in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

def clipped_cycle(start, end):
    c = cycle(range(0, 96))
    
    # Discard till start
    for _ in range(start):
        next(c)
        
    return c

c = clipped_cycle(90, 96)

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

what you get is an infinite output stream that cycles along.

```
90
91
92
93
94
95
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
.
.
.
```

to get a limited number of outputs:

```
n = 7
for _ in range(n):
    print(next(c))
```

gives

```
90
91
92
93
94
95
0
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I did not understand why you have defined `my_range = range(90, 100)`, if you are never going to use it.

You can use 'mod' in these cases.

Try this, short and effective

```
xlist = [i%96 for i in range(90,100)]
```